# Can't read SharedPreferences from another application

Tags: android

**EDITED:**

I have one app that writes to SharedPreferences like that:

```
    Context otherAppsContext = null;
    try {
        otherAppsContext = createPackageContext("AfroKeyboard.com.rob", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_PRIVATE", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    Editor prefsPrivateEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    prefsPrivateEditor.putString("layout02", jString);
    prefsPrivateEditor.putString("layout02name", "Russian Layout");
    prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
```

and another app that has to read from them

```
        Context otherAppsContext = null;
        try {
            otherAppsContext = createPackageContext("AfroKeyboard.com.rob", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        }

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_PRIVATE", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        Log.e( "name2" , "name2: "+sharedPreferences.getString("layout02name", "") );
```

but it returns empty.

What do you think might be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: travis,what problem u have with my answer?

Comment: doesn't seem to read... what should I put instead of PREFS_PRIVATE ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the app context. For example:

```
Context otherAppsContext = null;
try
{
     otherAppsContext = createPackageContext("<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME>", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e)
{
}
SharedPreferences prefs = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_FILE", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String result = prefs.getString("PREFERENCE_TAG_NAME", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
```

In this way you can read the content of the shared preference "PREFERENCE_TAG_NAME" that is saved in the file

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/<PREFS_FILE>.xml
```

You can do this in different apps that will work, but for that, the "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME" has to be the same.

If you want to change the value in any app you will need to change the mode of getSharedPreferences
from:

```
Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE
```

to:

```
Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE + Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE"
```

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer.  My issue is trying to access App A's SharedPreferences from my standalone BroadcastReceiver (called "SMSReceiver").  Eclipse reports that "The method createPackageContext(String, int) is undefined for the type SMSReceiver".  Is it possible to access that method from a Broadcast Receiver?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are accessing the SharedPreferences from another package, you need to use `Context.createPackageContext().getSharedPreferences()` instead of `this.getSharedPreferences()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Write SharedPreferences  as :

```
        Context otherAppsContext = null;
          try {
               otherAppsContext = createPackageContext("AfroKeyboard.com.rob", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
               } 
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
               }

myPrefs = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences("NAME_OF_SHARED_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("layout02", jString);
prefsEditor.putString("layout02name", "Russian Layout");
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Read SharedPreferences  as:

```
myPrefs = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences("NAME_OF_SHARED_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);         
String s = myPrefs.getString("layout02name", "") );
```

Comment: doesn't seem to read... what should I put instead of PREFS_PRIVATE ?

Comment: sorry friend,just put name of SharedPreferences  and see my edit ans

Comment: Thanks, i did call them "PREFS_PRIVATE" as above, but still no luck. :)

Comment: then just go /data/data/<package name>/shared_prefs in DDMS and see shared pref is created or not

Comment: you mean in file explorer in DDMS ? If so, then /data isn't expandable, i.e. there isn't anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

As late as this is, this is the way the I managed to make this work.

```
            String packageName ="com.yourpackage.yourname"
    Context otherAppsContext = null;
        try
        {
            otherAppsContext = createPackageContext(packageName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "will crash", 3).show();
        }
        SharedPreferences prefsother = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences(keyPackageName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        String key = prefsother.getString("key", "defValue");//use prefs normally here
```

Comment: `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` seems to be deprecated. How one still could achieve this?