# Changing one apps preferences from another app

Tags: android, share, sharedpreferences

I have two apps and I want one app to change preferences in another app.

Is it possible? If so, then how?

Comment: Already answer to a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928945/cant-read-sharedpreferences-fron-another-application/13419120#13419120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you need some passage between two applications.
If A application provides content provider, B application can access that content provider and change values in that provider.
Have a look this article http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use Content Providers. Put your settings in a database so that the other application can read.