# Sharing progress data between Android apps

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've nearly finished writing a game for the Android market.  I have a full version and a free version with half the levels.  I’ve read of a lot of people in similar situation with the following problem but can’t find a satisfactory solution:

My apps are separate but I want them to share data.  At least I want the full version to be able to read the free version’s progress data.  If a user finishes the free version, then installs the full, it needs to access the progress info because the first stage of the game is identical to the free version and the progress should be shared/mapped.

From what I have read the best way to save game progress is using SharedPreferences, which is what I’m doing and it’s working perfectly.

On searching for ways to share data I read that the best thing to do is to define the same android:sharedUserId in both AndroidManifest.xml files to be the same value and to ensure both apps are signed with the same key:

[What is sharedUserId in Android, and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783765/what-is-shareduserid-in-androidhow-can-i-used-shareduserid)

[multiple apps, sharing same data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139421/multiple-apps-sharing-same-data-directory)

I’ve done this and checked it’s working by using ApplicationInfo to see both app’s uids, which are the same.  However, I was then expecting to be able to read and write to SharedPrefs from both apps (running at different times) and to be reading/writing the same data.  But alas no.  If this does not make the apps share the same SharedPreferences, then what data are they sharing by specifying the same sharedUserId?

After some more digging some people seem to be saying I need to access the other app’s context first:

http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/25/getting-sharedpreferences-from-other-application-in-android/

[Can't read SharedPreferences fron another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928945/cant-read-sharedpreferences-fron-another-application)

So if I want App2 to access App1's data, this gives me the following code in App2’s Activity:

```
Context otherAppsContext = null;
try {
    otherAppsContext = createPackageContext("com.example.app1package",0);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
}
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences("TestShareData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But when I ask sharedPrefs for data it still just gives me data from the current app (App2 instead of App1).

Inspecting the otherAppsContext variable I’m not sure what it’s giving me.  It has an mBasePackageName property which is the package name of App2 (wrong).  But it also has an mPackageInfo property which appears to contain data about App1.

I just don’t know if I’m doing things the right way but am missing something or if this isn't the way to go at all.  I just want to link my 2 apps in such a way that one can read the other’s SharedPrefs.  How do most full versions of apps link to the free one's data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't you store the progress data on external storage media ?

Comment: Maybe that's a common way to do it but there's really not much to save and the SharedPrefs is working well in general.

Answer (score 0):

Sure this happens a lot but think I may have solved my own problem.

Both of my apps (full and free versions) are writing to sharedPrefs under the same name:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences( PREFS_NAME, 0 );
```

Where PREFS_NAME is the same for both apps.  When I ask for App1's Context from App2 it gives me a Context but it seems it's a Context that can access both Apps' data?

To explain when I get a Context for App1, from App2 and ask for SharedPreferences giving the name PREFS_NAME, I get the SharedPrefs from App2 instead.  But I tried changing the SharedPrefs name for App1 and then accessing that from the context in App2 and suddenly it picks up App1's data.

I don't really know what I'm getting back from the createPackageContext call, it seems to be a handle to both sets of data.  But I think I can just make my apps use different names for the SharedPrefs and have the full app just search for the free app's data if it needs to.